# Online chart with API to upload new data

Tags: api, web-services, charts, json

I'd like to provide a chart and include into an email which is created by some powershell code.

I am looking for a free online service that can render a chart based on my data (I want to upload a file / text to have a new chart), but couldn't find yet any service.

Does anyone know about this kind of online serice?